# MacOS/Remote Desktop to Windows Web Server 2008 through Linux proxy?

Tags: linux, proxy, remote-desktop

I want to connect to my Windows Server that is firewalled with restricted ip adresses, 
with a mobile MacBook with dynamic ip ([Remote Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx)). Can I use another Linux web server as a proxy to get a static ip, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way might be to use ssh port forwarding:

```
ssh -L 3389:winhost.com:3389 linuxuser@linuxhost.com
```

where winhost.com is the hostname of your windows server (has to be reachable by the linux server, i.e. not blocked by firewall). You would then connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead of the windows host to create an RDC connection.

Works like a charm here.

Comment: Work.. Have not been able to try it until now.
Works great, thanks for a simple solution I had not heard of.